# non-local variable uses anonymous type warning in C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, warnings

I'm compiling a C++ application which uses a C library with GCC 4.7.

when I compile, I receive the following warning:

```
warning: non-local variable ‘const ptg_t param’ uses anonymous type
warning: ‘typedef const struct<anonymous> ptg_t’ does not refer to the unqualified type, so it is not used for linkage
```

Why c++ treats that as warning, where c doesn't ?
Is there a way to fix it without changing the library header file where `ptg_t param` is defined ?

Comment: Because C++ and C are different languages with different rules?

Answer (score 3):

C++ is designed with the expectation that implementations will use the type name as part of the mangled symbol name. C is not designed with that expectation.

This is because C doesn't have function overloading whereas C++ does. In C++ you can have different entities with the same name, hence the need for name mangling.

So in C++, externals involving anonymous types are anomalies.

The preferred fix is to compile C code as C, not as C++. Then link it with the rest of your C++ program. When you include the header from C++, do it like:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "headername.h"
}
```

This bears repeating: do not compile C code as C++. C is not a subset of C++, and furthermore there are valid C programs which are also valid C++ but which have different required behavior in C++ from what they have in C. C++ is fairly easy to port to from C, but it is not fully backward-compatible with C.

Comment: I tried the using what you suggested with the extern, but the warning is still here.

Comment: @Mellowcandle: weird. Once you've followed my suggestions, the only thing compiled as C++ is the header file. If this extern object is defined in the header file then something is seriously wrong with the library, because it means that if multiple TUs in the same program both use the library, then there would be multiple definitions of the object (which is an error). If that's the case then you might have to fix the library.

Comment: Or if you really can't modify it despite having the source, you could write a wrapper for it in C, exposing a new header offering the same interface but with the dodgy object removed.